# Combobox autocomplete only working on some values?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, combobox, autocomplete

I have a combobox that is dynamically filled with datasources. The values are just number ranges (e.g. 1-50, 61-100). For some reason autocomplete doesn't always work:

example:
combobox is filled with 1-50
typing in 4 shows 40,41,42...
typing in 2 does not show 20...

Comment: here is a demo of the issue: https://youtu.be/pwUZkA9eIqI

Answer (score 0):

Your combo box contains the exact value "2".  The combobox autocomplete will not suggest a different value for "2" since an exact match exists.  In your video demo a "3" elicits an autocomplete suggestion since there is no value that exactly matches "3".

If you want to force autocomplete to suggest double-digit values, you could look into specifying an [AutoCompleteCustomSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletecustomsource?view=netframework-4.8) that excludes all single-digit values.

Comment: Thanks. This explains the issue perfectly. I'll review my options on this form. I noticed using method autocomplete AND autosuggest works a bit as I'd like.